# Amazon SNS limit on SMS messages

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have been using Amazon SNS to send SMS messages to clients. My issue is Clients are able to receive SMS only on the start of the month. I guess there is some limit I am struck with. Can any one help me out?

**Code**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS({
    region: region,
});

export default function SMS(phone, body) {
    var params = {
        Message:  body,
        PhoneNumber: phone,
    };
    sns.setSMSAttributes(
        {
            attributes: {
                DefaultSMSType: "Transactional"
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    );
    sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response
    });

}
```

Comment: Turn on [Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/) to obtain more information about message failures.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check to see if you are hitting a 'no quota left' error message from the SNS to verify if your suspicion of AWS limits on SMS are affecting you.  If they are, you can request a limit increase by opening a ticket with AWS support.  That process for SMS increases in [talked about here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-sms-spending-limit-increase/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending to the US, there are additional requirements. I recommend reading about:

- [SMS Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox.html)
- [Requesting quota increases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-spend-threshold.html)
- [Sending restrictions for US](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-us-requirements.html)